# 'Cannot install in Homebrew on Intel processor in ARM default prefix' on an intel based macbook

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I had brew working but with last brew update, this error started to come up:

`Cannot install in Homebrew on Intel processor in ARM default prefix`

Comment: Try run is under Rosetta Terminal: https://osxdaily.com/2020/11/18/how-run-homebrew-x86-terminal-apple-silicon-mac/

Comment: See: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/9130

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue was due to where the brew installation was located: `/opt/homebrew`, which I guess had been configured in latest brew update as 'prefix' for 'ARM' type installations.

To resolve this, I moved the complete installation to '/usr/local/homebrew', which resolved the issue for me.

Though this rendered some of the formulae as stale (android-toolkit).

`brew doctor` gave a warning about the brew prefix, solving which resolved the stated error.

Comment: how do you move it?

Comment: @HenryM, ```mv /opt/homebrew /usr/local/homebrew```